# Como iterar dentro de pd.iloc?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, excel, pandas

Tengo un archivo Excel de la siguiente manera:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito leer este archivo Excel de nombre `2023-2.xlsx` e imprimir en distintos archivos cada dia por ejemplo al leer este archivo que se ve en la imagen , deberia impimir 4 archivos con nombres: `01-02-2023.xlsx` , `02-02-2023.xlsx` , `03-02-2023.xlsx` , `04-02-2023.xlsx` , con sus datos correspondientes . Se deberian ver archivos asi: [image: Dia 1]
[image: dia2]

Y asi tambien los otros dias(ya que el dataframe orignal posee todos los dias del mes), como se podria iterar los dias sin tener que escribir todas las columnas por dia como lo tengo en mi codigo??

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import glob
import os
import csv
all_files = glob.glob("C:/Users/ep_irojaso/Desktop/PROGRAMA DESEMPEÑO/saturn/2023-2.xlsx")
file_list = []
for i,f in enumerate(all_files):   
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
   
first = df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
second = df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,7,8,9,10]]
third = df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,11,12,13,14]]

firstWriter = pd.ExcelWriter("first.xlsx") 
pd.DataFrame(first).to_excel(firstWriter)  
firstWriter.save()

secondWriter = pd.ExcelWriter("second.xlsx") 
pd.DataFrame(second).to_excel(secondWriter) 
secondWriter.save()

thirdWriter = pd.ExcelWriter("third.xlsx") 
pd.DataFrame(third).to_excel(thirdWriter) 
thirdWriter.save()
```

Comment: Podés hacer una función que tome el mes y año incial y el mes y año final y vaya agregando a una lista las columnas intermedias. En `df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]`, el `[0,1,2,3...]` es una lista, por lo que podés retornar directamente dicha lista y hacer por ejemplo `df.iloc[:, getcolumns(1, 2012, 10, 2021)]`

Answer (score 0):

**Una solución**

```
import pandas as pd

def make_exels_per_day(df, startcol, size):
    numfile = 1
    first_cols = range(startcol)

    for i in range(startcol, len(df.columns), size):
        cols = [*first_cols, *range(i, i + size)]

        df.iloc[:,cols].to_excel("excel%s.xlsx" % numfile)
        numfile += 1
        
size = 4
startcol = 3

df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(startcol + size * 30))])

make_exels_per_day(df, startcol, size)
```

**Explicación**

La función make_exels_per_day toma un DataFrame (df), la columna inicial (startcol) y la cantidad de columnas que ocupa un día (size).

Lo primero que hace es usar un objeto range para obtener todas las columnas del 0 a startcol.

De ahí, iteramos sobre un rango que inicia con startcol, finaliza en la ultima columna - 1 y va dando pasos de size.

En cada iteración, formamos la lista de columnas desempaquetando el rango con las primeras startcol columnas y las columnas entre i y i + size - 1. Donde i es la primera columna del día visitado actualmente.

Luego, recurrimos a iloc y le pasamos la lista de columnas, generando con ello un excel e incrementamos en uno el contador que nos ayuda a dar nombre a los archivos.

**Requisitos para el buen funcionamiento**

Sin que el dataframe cumpla estos requisitos, la función no funcionará bien:

- Todos los días deben tener la misma cantidad de columnas
- Las columnas deben tener un id numerica, contando desde 0. Es decir, 0 1 2 3...

Comment: El unico problema que me surge con este codigo , es que solo se imprime la fila 0

Comment: Mi código no imprime nada. No entiendo a que te refieres.

Comment: me refiero a que la función solo extrae la fila 0 y necesito todas las filas

Comment: y necesito que extraiga todas las filas del documento

Comment: Eso ya es cuestión de como usar el iloc. Yo solo me basé en el código presentado. Mas tarde veo como resolverlo.

Comment: Mi código funciona para todas las filas. El dataframe de prueba tiene una sola fila. Quizá por eso crees eso.